# Why wont UI update on RaisePropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, binding

I have a static IList which acts as a repository in a static class:

//static class Settings

```
public static IList RecentSearchedRepo = new ObservableCollection<object>();
```

and an IList located in another class which I bind my UI grid to :

//component class

```
private IList recentsearch = new ObservableCollection<object>();
public IList RecentSearch
{
    get
    {
        return recentsearch;
    }
    set
    {
        recentsearch = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("RecentSearch");
    }
}
```

I add objects to RecentSearchedRepo :

```
RecentSearchedRepo.add(searchitem)
```

then set RecentSearch to the static list

```
RecentSearch = Settings.RecentSearchedRepo;
```

XAML snippet:

```
<GridLayout:RecentSearchGrid x:Name="recentSearchGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentSearch}" />
```

snippet from RecentSearchGrid class which extends UserControl:

```
 public IList ItemsSource
 {
     get
     {
         return GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty) as IList;
     }
     set
     {
         SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
     }
}

private static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
                    DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IList), typeof(RecentSearchGrid), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged));


private static void OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
     RecentSearchGrid source = d as RecentSearchGrid;

     if (source != null)
     {
      source.setListforgrid(source.ItemsSource);
     }
}
```

The problem is when I add the first item to `RecentSearchedRepo` the UI is updated , but on every subsequent add the UI does not update.

Comment: have you thought about changing the public static IList to protected static IList, also is this a winform or asp.net..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE , C#. Not a form or web based. The code is meant to run on an XBOX console.  Also does changing from public to protected make a difference when binding.

Comment: You're currently raising the event when you set a new list, not when the current list is modified.  You need to fire the appropriate event when the collection is modified.

Comment: @Fabii: Which binding technology are you using? (Code might be useful)

Comment: @Servy: Depends on the binding technology. Standard WPF itemscollections, e.g., understand ObservableCollections (INotifyCollectionChanged) and will update the view based on changes to the collection itself without any explicit user-space notification.

Comment: @GregD And given that he's not seeing that happening, he's clearly not doing that, and given that he *is* firing an event when he sets this property, it's a logical assumption to make.  Odds are he's either binding the wrong event, or he needs one event to fire another, etc.

Comment: @Servy , I'm using ObservableCollections  so it should update the UI based on a change to the collection. It updates on the first add but not the subsequent ones.

Comment: @Fabii: What's a "RecentSearchGrid"?  I'm not aware of that as any standard control. It's a custom subclass of ItemsControl (guessing from the presence of ItemsSource)?

Comment: @GregD , yes it is a custom subclass of UserControl.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
RecentSearch = Settings.RecentSearchedRepo;
```

Try doing:

```
RecentSearch.Clear();
var freshData = Settings.RecentSearchedRepo;
if (freshData != null)
    foreach (var item in freshData)
        RecentSearch.Add(item);
```

You were killing the binding by reassigning the reference.

**EDIT**: After yours

You're doing it backwards: that `OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged` shouldn't be setting the source, it shouldn't be there at all actually. 
You must bind, in *RecentSearchGrid.xaml*, to the `ItemsSource` dependency property declared in *RecentSearchGrid.xaml.cs*

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the case. `RecentSearch` isn't a dependency property and, thus, doesn't have a binding assigned to it. Rather, it's a binding source that properly notifies when it's been changed.

Comment: I'm waiting for his feedback on this, because ItemsSource in his XAML is a custom property that he exposed. Now, the fact is that the first reference that is assigned is displayed, so if he always keeps the same reference, it should work.

Comment: Good point. The problem could be the implementation of the RecentSearchGrid b/c it's derived from UserControl, not an ItemsControl (which would guarantee correct ItemsSource semantics).

Comment: I will add code from the RecentSearchGrid  , so you can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there's enough information here to answer your question. The following simple application mirrors the scenario that I see described in the question and it works as expected:

```
// MySettings.cs
public static class MySettings
{
    public static IList RecentSearchedRepo = new ObservableCollection<object>();
}

// MyVm.cs
public class MyVm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IList recentSearch = new ObservableCollection<object>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MyVm()
    {
        this.RecentSearch = MySettings.RecentSearchedRepo;
    }

    public IList RecentSearch
    {
        get { return recentSearch; }
        set 
        { 
            recentSearch = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("RecentSearch");
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null) this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }
}

// MainWindow.xaml.cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Initialization as described in the question
        MySettings.RecentSearchedRepo.Add("SearchItem1");
        MySettings.RecentSearchedRepo.Add("SearchItem2");

        this.DataContext = new MyVm();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Add a new item later
        MySettings.RecentSearchedRepo.Add("NewlyAddedSearchItem");
    }
}

// MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="ScratchWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Add new Search Item" Click="Button_Click_1" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RecentSearch}" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

I'm going to try putting on my psychic hat and ask if, perhaps, you are adding additional items to the wrong collection.  Does the collection get recreated and placed at the binding after a single item is added, but later items are added to the original collection instead of the new one?

Given that you stated RecentSearchGrid is a UserControl, we can also infer that the implementation of ItemsSource may be a custom one rather than the standard one that would be inherited from an ItemsControl. It's possible that the RecentSearchGrid is breaking the binding incorrectly in there somehow.

I agree with Baboon. What is the purpose of `OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged`?  In a typical implementation, I wouldn't expect that to be there.

Comment: I dumped out collection size after each add and it reflects that object are infact being added. The UI is just not updating.

Comment: Which collection are you dumping the size of?  If you're dumping the size immediately after the add statement, that proves nothing because of _course_ that's where you're adding an item. My question is whether that's the _same_ collection that you're bound to.  How often does your PropertyChanged event get raised for that collection?

Comment: The PropertyChanged  gets raised each time I make the assignment RecentSearch = Settings.RecentSearchedRepo; I dump out both the size for RecentSearch and RecentSearchedRepo.

Comment: Why are you assigning it more than once?  That's unexpected. When you say `RecentSearch = Settings.RecentSearchedRepo`, you're making both references point to the same collection. The only reason to assign it again is if you're creating a new collection (which could easily lead to the scenario that I described).

Comment: Sorry I am not understanding how that would be. Settings.RecentSearchedRepo  is in a static class, when an object is added to Settings.RecentSearchedRepo , how would I reference the updated collection without RecentSearch = Settings.RecentSearchedRepo ?

Comment: Calling `RecentSearch = Settings.RecentSearchedRepo` makes `RecentSearch` _reference_ the same collection as `Settings.RecentSearchedRepo`.  It does _not_ copy the collection, it makes _another variable reference the same collection._  Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx, the section on Reference Types in particular (about 2/3rds of the way down)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22195/discussion-between-fabii-and-greg-d)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be as follow:
 **OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged** will not get called, if the instance does not change.
From WPF point of view, when you **RaisePropertyChangeEvent**, but the instance of the bound collection does not change, **PropertyChange** handler will not be called at all.

Is `Settings.RecentSearchedRepo` the same instance through the lifetime of the app?

Comment: Yes it should be the same instance through the lifetime of the app.

Comment: Then try to do something like RecentSearch = new ObservableCollection<...> (Settings.RecentSearchedRepo); and see if this works

Comment: ObservableCollection does not allow for a constructor that takes 1 argument.  This is not Wpf , it is C# for Xbox.